# number which is Square or can be written as sum of two squares python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, sum, square

I created a program in python to check if a given number is square or can be written as sum of two squares, but it doesn't work.please help me.

```
def sum(num):
    def m(a):
        b=a
        for item in range(a):
            b=b-1
            if a==b*b:
                return(a)
    c=num
    for item in range(1,num):
        c-=1
        if m(c)==c and m(d)==d:
            print(num)
```

Comment: what do you mean doesn't work? You would need to provide what you expected as output as well.

Comment: what do you think d is?

Comment: Are you trying to define a function within a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if something is a perfect square if the int of its square root squared is its target

```
def is_square(n):
    return int(n**0.5)**2 == n
```

the second part is a little harder (though not hard)

first you only need to check ints up to the square root of the target and then add 1

```
for i in range(0,int(target**0.5+1)):
```

then you need to go over the remaining numbers you can get teh remaining numbers with

```
    for j in range(i,int((target-i**2)**0.5+1)
```

then all you have to do is check if i squared + j squared is your target if it is than `i,j` is one of your solutions